# How to check if native bind function is available with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Is is possible to check with Modernizer whether native browser's bind function (or any other native browser's function) is available or I'm using pollyfill?

Comment: Modernizr docs say they include a polyfill for it by default; you can check whether it exists without Modernizr with `typeof Function.prototype.bind`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but you can very easily create your own tests with Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/docs/#addtest You'll need to check for `Function.prototype.bind`.